# Не могу подключиться к mqtt-брокеру в приложении tauri + vue

Tags: vue.js, mqtt, tauri

Пишу приложение, используя tauri + vue. Мне нужно подключаться к mqtt-брокеру. В режиме отладке всё работает, всё хорошо (использую библиотеку mqtt.js). Но когда делаю build - не подключается к брокеру, как будто после билда приложение не умеет этого делать. И даже не ошибки, ни какого либо сообщения нет, что бы понять в чем дело. Эта проблема решаема?

P.S. Бот попросил уточнить проблему, поэтому попробую так:

Можно ли из приложения, написанном с использованием Tauri + Vue подключиться к mqtt-брокеру? И если можно то подскажите, пожалуйста, как. Пол дня не могу нагуглить решение.

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Answer (score 0):

Настройте сборку так чтоб подключение к mqtt происходило только с клиента. Возможно оно попало в ssr.

Инициализацию подключения перенеси в onMounted например. Или используй функционал Фреймворка если пишешь не на голом vue.